# Print content from a vector of a class

Tags: c++

I would like to print the content from a vector that is in my class Board

```
class Board {
public:
    Board(const string &filename);


private:
    int numLines, numColumns;
    vector<Ship> ships;
    vector <vector <int> > board;

 };
```

Ship class:

```
class Ship {
public:
    Ship(char symb, PositionChar pos, char ori, unsigned int tam, unsigned int cor);

 private:

    char symbol;
    PositionChar position;

    char orientation;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int color;
    string status;


 };
```

Why I can't do something like this?

```
cout << b1.ships[1].color << endl;
```

just to test ofc

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

> Why I can't do something like this?
>
> ```
> cout << b1.ships[1].color << endl;
> ```

Because `ships` is a private member of `Board` and thus not accessible from outside the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `ships` as a **private** variable of all `class Board` objects. Therefore you cannot access it from outside `Board` class.

As for the `operator[]`, if you have declared `ships` vector as **public**, it would be perfectly fine to write:

```
cout << b1.ships[1].color << endl;
```

EDIT: Regarding discussion in the comments, i.e. accesing member variables of `Board` and `Ship` objects: you can either make the `Board` [friend](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) of `Ship` or create public getters for the member variables you want to access, for example the class `Ship` could look like this:

```
class Ship {
public:
    Ship(char symb, PositionChar pos, char ori, unsigned int tam, unsigned int cor);

 private:

    char symbol;
    PositionChar position;

    char orientation;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int color;
    string status;
public:
    unsigned int getSize() { return size;}

 };
```

Comment: And I can't do that because color is private. I understand why I can't do that but in this project classes are already declared and I "can't" change them. I'm stuggling because now I need to put the ships on the board and I cant figure out how to get the color, size, orientation, etc
I just cant acceed those parameters :\

Comment: @Verance Can't you just add public accessor method to the `Board` class?

Comment: You mean put the vector of Ships public? I can and I did it but then all the attributes from class Ship are private and I can't access them

Comment: So then you can write public accessor method for the `Ship` class.

Comment: You mean put everything on public and then access?

Comment: Accept the answer if you've found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

1- be sure that `cout << b1.ships[1].color << endl;` is used in a function which is `friend` to `Board class` and `Ships class`  including `int main()`.
to access private members

2- be sure that you declared and defined `Ship` before `Board` because vector is taking a copy of your ship objects.